# Java Interop: Apply @JvmName to getters of properties in interface or abstract class

Tags: java, interface, annotations, kotlin, getter

Usually, we can write the following code in kotlin:

```
val hasValue : Boolean
    @JvmName("hasValue") get() = true
```

This will generate the method `hasValue()` instead of `getHasValue()` for **Java interop**.

However, in an interface, this gives me a compile error:

```
val hasValue : Boolean
   @JvmName("hasValue") get
```

The same goes for the following declaration in an abstract class:

```
abstract val hasValue : Boolean
    @JvmName("hasValue") get
```

So here is my question: How can I tell the kotlin compiler to use `hasValue()` instead of `getHasValue()` for getters (and setters) of properties in a kotlin interfaces?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a workaround, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31420

Simply suppress this `INAPPLICABLE_JVM_NAME` error with annotation: `@Suppress("INAPPLICABLE_JVM_NAME")`

Comment: Note that this should be done to **every override** of this member, and see issue comments in YouTrack for details.

Answer (score 12):

I think Kotlin has some restriction on using `@JvmName` on `open`/`override` property/function. Prohibiting the use of `@JvmName` on `open`/`override` function can avoid having different jvmName on the interface/superclass and subclass.

In the following example, I am trying to annotate the overrided property getter with a jvmName (`hasValueImpl`) which is different from the interface (`hasValue`) and it gives compilation error:

> '@JvmName' annotation is not applicable to this declaration

```
interface Abstract {

    @get:JvmName("hasValue")        //Compile error
    val hasValue: Boolean
        get() = false
}

open class Impl : Abstract {

    @get:JvmName("hasValueImpl")    //Compile error
    final override val hasValue: Boolean
        get() = false

    @get:JvmName("hasValue2")       //Compile error if hasValue2 is open
    val hasValue2: Boolean
        get() = false
}
```

Comment: Your argumentation makes sense for override properties, but not for abstract/open properties that override nothing. Although it would mean that if you override an annotated property you'd need to inherit its jvm signature

Comment: You're right, `@JvmName` is prohibited both for overridden and overridable functions.
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/19e38bbc725ec68c9d40bc5c4ad8945266df7231/compiler/frontend.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/jvm/checkers/declarationCheckers.kt#L141
@msrd0, this answer is correct and should be accepted.

Comment: @Miha_x64 This answer is correct but yet does not answer the question "how can I tell the Kotlin compiler ...", while it would answer the question "can I tell the Kotlin compiler ..."

Comment: The answer is 'no way'.

Comment: Note that Kotlin does not allow the annotation on `inline` classes.

Answer (score 5):

I turns out, this is possible:

```
interface Foo {
    val bar: String
        @get:JvmName("getAwesomeBar") get
}
```

---

However, it is interesting that this does NOT work:

```
interface Foo {
    @get:JvmName("getAwesomeBar") 
    val bar: String
}
```

But, this does work:

```
class Foo {
    val bar: String
        @JvmName("getAwesomeBar") get() = "My bar value"
}
```

and this works too!

```
class Foo {
    @get:JvmName("getAwesomeBar") 
    val bar: String
        get() = "My bar value"
}
```

---

Why you need to have the extra `get:` when doing this in interfaces is beyond me. I'm sure there is a reason for it.

Comment: There is a reason: using `get() = "My bar value"` is like hardcoding the value for the `val` in your getter body, so you don't need a backing field, whereas just having a `get` requires a backing field to be generated, AFAIK.

Comment: Note that the first one doesn't seem to actually change the java getter name although the syntax is accepted (JVM/1.6.0-M1).