How to resolve "Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature" for class member variable?
I have the following Kotlin code
interface ReminderHolderOwner {
    val childFragmentManager: FragmentManager
}

class ReminderDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), ReminderHolderOwner {
    override val childFragmentManager: FragmentManager
        get() = super.getChildFragmentManager()

I am getting error

Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM
signature
(getChildFragmentManager()Landroidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager;):
fun <get-childFragmentManager>(): FragmentManager defined in com.xxx.input.reminder.ReminderDialogFragment
fun getChildFragmentManager(): FragmentManager defined in com.xxx.input.reminder.ReminderDialogFragment

May I know, how can I resolve such an error? Thanks.
Please do not close the thread. It is not a duplicated question.
Applying @get:JvmName("getChildFragmentManager") will not resolve the issue. We will get error
annotation is not applicable to this declaration

The answer provided in Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature is meant for function parameter, not member variable.

No. It doesn't solve the mentioned issue.

I don't think you looked at all the answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351041/1197251.
You've created an interface that have a property childFragmentManager which translates to getChildFragmentManager in the JVM, which clashes with the Fragment getChildFragmentManger. Name it something else.

May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504279/6395627

rename your childFragmentManager variable to be something else, such as childFm, reminderFragmentMager, baseFragmentMager etc

To resolve the "Accidental override" error for a class member variable in Kotlin, you can explicitly implement the interface property in the class instead of overriding it. Here's how you can do it:
interface ReminderHolderOwner {
    val childFragmentManager: FragmentManager
}

class ReminderDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), ReminderHolderOwner {
    override val childFragmentManager: FragmentManager by lazy {
        super.getChildFragmentManager()
    }
}

In this code, instead of overriding the childFragmentManager property directly, you use the by lazy delegate to initialize it when it's accessed for the first time. This ensures that the property is only initialized once and avoids the "Accidental override" error.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
